# How to split a html file in modules?

Tags: html

I have a single HTML file with more than one thousand lines and it's really hard to maintain it at this point even though sections are separated with comments so i can jump to it using search. Nonetheless it seems very impractical.

I don't want to use frameworks because it's just a simple front end website and I see no reason to insert another learning curve.

What are my options at this point?

Comment: if no framework just whats built in then its web components, or use fetch() etc to pull in partials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your options are either server-side tech that supports includes (e.g. [php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)) or running a [static site generator](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2020/04/14/what-is-a-static-site-generator-and-3-ways-to-find-the-best-one/) like [eleventy](https://www.11ty.dev/), which might violate your "no frameworks" criteria, but could accomplish what you're after with minimal learning curve.

(This isn't an eleventy endorsement, by the way--I've never used it--but it looks like a zero-config setup that would do what you're trying to do with minimal hassle.)

With eleventy and pug templates you'd just do:

```
<html>
<body>
  {% include ./header.pug %}
  {% include ./sidebar.pug %}
  <div> ...inline content... </div>
  {% include ./footer.pug %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Figures. I do use php for api calls, but haven't used it before to mimic this partial views system before. It's probably the best approach

Comment: Here's the [php include documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php).

Answer (score 3):

You could split it up into seperate files then just use javascript and a base file to include them all back in again. Use a js library like this: https://gist.github.com/PseudoDevelopers/41657e10c0a527253c3fb5a6d4a2a2ee and the following code:

```
<script> include('path/to/file.html', document.currentScript) </script>
```

Something like that?

Comment: "then just use jquery and a base file to include them all back in again." - Why is jQuery needed?

Comment: really would like to avoid using jquery just for this. Seems like just another use a lib to help your problem

Comment: Edited to remove jquery I was thinking of another solution to start with. Its just a javascript libarary. I dont think there is a way of doing it without some sort of library.

Comment: How about split it up and then call them back in objects? 

<OBJECT data="file_to_include.html">
Warning: file_to_include.html could not be included.
</OBJECT>